# How to replace <p><br></p> from end of string that contain whitespaces, linebreaks and tab jumps? Regex?

Tags: php, regex

I consider myself still a newbie to regex and have the following challenge:

My users post content that contain one or more "line breaks" at the end. These "line breaks" are `<p><br></p>` with varying amounts of whitespace between the tags. Sometimes, more than one `<br>` is in each paragraph. Some examples:

```
<p>

<br> 
</p>
```

```
<p>
     <br> 
</p>
```

```
<p><br> <br> 
</p>
```

```
<p>
 <br> 
</p>
```

How can I remove these paragraphs from the end of each piece of content, while also removing the contained `<br>`s, spaces, line breaks, and tabs?

Comment: use `\s*` to match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

Comment: I don't see `<br />` in any of the examples, just `<br>`

Comment: don't even try a regex. use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) instead.

Comment: Just try `<p>\s*<br\s*\/?>\s*<\/p>`

Comment: Idea for workaround: I just realized, I could also try to remove all HTML tags in the end that do not contain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php
$strings[] = 'foo<p>

<br> 
</p>';
$strings[] = 'foo<p>
     <br> 
</p>';
$strings[] = 'foo<p><br><br> 
</p>';
$strings[] = 'foo<p>
 <br> 
</p>';

foreach($strings as $string){
 // \s* matches any number of whitespace characters (" ", \t, \n, etc)
 // (?:...)+ matches one or more (without capturing the group)
 // $ forces match to only be made at the end of the string
 $string = preg_replace("/(?:<p>\s*(?:<br>\s*)+<\/p>\s*)+$/", "", $string);

 echo $string."\n---\n";
}
```

Output is:

> foo
>   ---
>   foo
>   ---
>   foo
>   ---
>   foo
>   ---

Comment: Thank you! As I wrote end of string, do I need to add the `+$`? Like `preg_replace("/<p>\s*<br>\s*<\/p>+$/", "", $string);` And there are no characters after the closing `</p>` tag, but sometimes the users write two or three times `<p> <br> <p>` successive in the end.

Comment: What if they're not separated just by `\s` but `\t` and/or `\n` as well?

Comment: @Ben `\s*` to match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV I've updated my answer to match multiple instances of `<p><br></p>`. You would actually want `(?:` at the beginning, and `)+` at the end to match multiple. The `(?:` starts a "non-capturing" group (so it doesn't get assigned a `$#`), the `)` closes it, and the `+` looks for one or more.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it just works! Last addition: I just saw that a user entered couple of `<br>`s inside the p tag. So I have changed your regex from `/(?:<p>\s*<br>\s*<\/p>\s*)+$/` to `/(?:<p>\s*(<br>)+\s*<\/p>\s*)+$/` for matching one or more BRs but it does not work. Do you have any last suggestion on this? Thanks.

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV Are the `<br>`s consecutive? Or is there whitespace between them? If there is whitespace, you'll want `(<br>\s*)+` instead of `(<br>)+\s*` to match whitespace between the `<br>`s.

Comment: Each `<br>` is on a new line. The `(<br>\s*)+` seems to work for this case. Thanks a thousand!