# PHP: Clean HTML by merging line breaks and removing whitespaces properly

Tags: php, html

I am using a WYSIWYG editor and have a bunch of regular expressions that take care of dirty HTML. Reason: My users often hit the enter key too often and produce many redundant new lines such as:

- `<br><br><br>` ...
- `<p>  <br /> </p>`
- `<p>  <br /><br /> </p>`
- `<p>  <br /> </p>`
- `<p>  &nbsp; <br /> </p>`
- `<p>  &nbsp; <br /> </p>`
- and many more varieties including `p`, `&nbsp;` and `br`

This is how I try to fight such inputs currently, trying to merge many successive line breaks into 1, using many different regular expressions:

```
// merge empty p tags into one
// http://stackoverflow.com/q/16809336/1066234
$content = preg_replace('/((<p\s*\/?>\s*)&nbsp;(<\/p\s*\/?>\s*))+/im', "<p>&nbsp;</p>\n", $content);

// remove sceditor's: <p>\n<br>\n</p> from end of string
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269584/how-to-replace-pbr-p-from-end-of-string-that-contain-whitespaces-linebrea
// \s* matches any number of whitespace characters (" ", \t, \n, etc)
// (?:...)+ matches one or more (without capturing the group)
// $ forces match to only be made at the end of the string
$content = preg_replace("/(?:<p>\s*(<br>\s*)+\s*<\/p>\s*)+$/", "", $content);

// remove sceditor's double: http://http://
$content = str_replace('http://http://', 'http://', $content);

// remove spaces from end of string (&nbsp;)
$content = preg_replace('/(&nbsp;)+$/', '', $content);

// remove also <p><br></p> from end of string
$content = preg_replace('/(<p><br><\/p>)+$/', '', $content);

// remove line breaks from end of string - $ is end of line, +$ is end of line including \n
// html with <p>&nbsp;</p>
$content = preg_replace('/(<p>&nbsp;<\/p>)+$/', '', $content);
$content = preg_replace('/(<br>)+$/', '', $content);

// remove line breaks from beginning of string
$content = preg_replace('/^(<p>&nbsp;<\/p>)+/', '', $content);
```

I am searching for a new solution. Is there any HTML parser that I can tell to merge line breaks and whitespaces? Or maybe someone has another approach to that problem.

The regex solutions above do not seem proper enough because new combinations of line break "attempts" by my users slip through.

Comment: I'd try solving the issue at the WYSIWYG level. Regex 1 doesn't need the `m` modifier, you might want the `s` modifier there..

Comment: Did I understand you correct? You want to remove every empty line break?

Comment: @AMartinNo1 Yes, everywhere where a user has put several line breaks I want to merge them into 1 line break. Problem is the 'structure' of the line breaks is quite unpredictable, see examples above.

Comment: I see. What if someone wants to have more than one line break for whatever reason?

Comment: From my experience over a couple of years I can tell that most users think that line breaks would help the visual impression of the question and add about 5 - 10 line breaks in the end of the question creating unnecessary white space. But you are right, we could allow 2 line breaks. Still the issue above remains unsolved :)

Comment: So, users add line breaks on purpose. I wouldn't try to remove them afterwards then. Anyway, as @chris85 I would try to solve it on WYSIWYG level as well. Like `IF key eq enter THEN addLineBreak();` the method `addLineBreak` adds only a linebreak if there is no empty one yet.

Comment: I cannot control the WYSIWYG... and need to solve this problem serverside.

Comment: Then to start I'd use entity decode to `&nbsp;` and spaces are the same.

Comment: A step by step solution would be: 1. Get the enclosing p tag, 2. check its content 3. if the content is br and whitespaces only and \n \r empty the p tag. 4. check all $content if we have several p tags behind each other, 5. merge them into on p tag. - That is why I thought of a kind of HTML parser.

Comment: I have just remembered a library that I have used for another project and asked the developer [over there](http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=848). I hope he will answer so that we have a solution to the problem.

Comment: Have you thought about using [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)? It can remove empty tags. Since you are using a WYSIWYG editor, you should use this any way to prevent users from sending you page breaking HTML or XSS attacks.

Comment: I am running htmlawed in the background, and I guess this could solve it too. I hope the developer is answering my question over there that I can post an answer.

Comment: Just for reference, I post the answer of the HTMLawed developer here: http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=848

Answer (score 0):

I have developed following snippet that removes duplicate `br`-Tags.

```
<?php
$content = "<h1>Hello World</h1><p>Test\r\n<br>\r\n<br >\r\n<br    >\r\n<br/>Test\r\n<br />\r\n<br    /></p>";

echo "<code>{$content}</code><hr>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";

$contentStripped = preg_replace('/(<br {0,}\/{0,1}>(\\r|\\n){0,}){2,}/', '<br class="reduced" />', $content);
echo "<code>{$contentStripped}</code>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";
```

[image]

**You may have to add more test cases.**

Answer (score -1):

You can use nl2br(strip_tags($content)) instead of above long code.

Comment: The problem with `strip_tags` is that it removes every `br`-tag but he wants to remove not every `br`-tag. Also he would have to add almost every html tag to the allowed list so that not unwanted tags will be removed.

Comment: Nope, I have a bunch of other HTML inside that must survive. Using strip_tags would remove all tags. This solution is not acceptable.

Comment: strip_tags doesn't remove all htmls tags and it does allow second parameters which excludes certain html tags.

string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php